# SFTP: return number of files in remote directory?

Tags: bash, sftp

I sent a batch of files to a remote server via SFTP. If it were a local directory I could do something like this `ls -l | wc -l` to get the total number of files. However, with SFTP, I get an error `Can't ls: "/|" not found`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
echo ls -l | sftp server | grep -v '^sftp' | wc -l
```

If you want to count the files in a directory the directory path should be put after the ls -l command like

```
echo ls -l /my/directory/ | sftp server | grep -v '^sftp' | wc -l
```

Answer (score 3):

**Use a batch file to run commands remotely and get the data back to work with in bash:**

Make your batch file called `mybatch.txt` with these sftp commands:

```
cd your_directory/your_sub_directory
ls -l
```

Save it out and give it 777 permissions.

```
chmod 777 mybatch.txt
```

Then run it like this:

```
sftp your_username@your_server.com < mybatch.txt
```

It will prompt you for the password, enter it.

Then you get the output dumped to bash terminal.  So you can pipe that to `wc -l` like this:

```
sftp your_user@your_server.com < mybatch.txt | wc -l
Connecting to your_server.com...
your_user@your_server.com's password:
8842
```

The 8842 is the number of lines returned by `ls -l` in that directory.

Instead of piping it to wc, you could dump it to a file for parsing to determine how many files/folders.

Comment: Whatever it is that you are attempting to accomplish here, **`chmod 777` is wrong** and a **security problem.** There is no universe in which it makes sense to grant unknown users write access to a script which you are about to execute. You are probably looking for 755, though in this particular case, there should be no need to mess with the permissions at all (or even use a physical file at all really, actually). At your reputation level, I would really expect better.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I have found is to use the [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/) client which supports a shell-like syntax to transfer the output of remote ftp commands to local processes.

For example using the pipe character:

```
lftp -c 'connect sftp://user_name:password@host_name/directory; ls -l | wc -l'
```

This will make lftp spawn a local `wc -l` and give it the output of the remote `ls -l` ftp command on its stdin.

Shell redirection syntax is also supported and will write directly to local files:

```
lftp -c 'connect sftp://user_name:password@host_name/directory; ls -l >list.txt'
```

Thus a file named `list.txt` containing the remote file listing will be created in the current folder on the local machine. Use `>>` to append instead.

Works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would use sftp batch file.
Create a file called batchfile and enter "ls -l" in it.
Then run

```
sftp -b batchfile user@sftpHost | wc -l
```