# Count number of files in a remote directory using SFTP

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I am writing a script in bash and I need to count how many files starting with ddd that are in a remote directory using SFTP. After it download each file, so them I can compare how many files had in the remote directory and how many files were downloaded. Check if they match and such.

I was doing something like this:

`echo ls -l | sftp "user@$123.45.67.8:/home/user/datafolder/ddd*" | wc -l`

The one above works, but when I run this it downloads all the files to my local folder, which I do not want.

How can I count the number of files and do not download them. I want to download them in another part of the code.

Comment: `FTP` is file transfer protocol.
I think what your looking for is `SSH`

Comment: @user3240704 SFTP, like FTP, [allows certain commands such as listing remote directories](http://www.tecmint.com/sftp-command-examples/) (and that would be good reading for the OP)

Comment: It does, and syntactically OPs code [is correct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25412497/sftp-return-number-of-files-in-remote-directory). However FTP/SFTP being a _file transfer protocol_ may _transfer the files_ which is the feature OP is trying to avoid. 

So using SSH would solve the issue.

Comment: @user3240704 SFTP *can* transfer files. SFTP can also *list* remote files without performing any content transfer. The OP is asking how to *count* the number of remote files without downloading said files. This can done by counting the number of file names returned from the *listing* result.

Comment: I don't understand why I am getting downvoted. The code above works, like if I remove the ddd* it shows how many files are inside that folder without downloading. Should I change the approach to ssh?

Comment: @user2864740 you're right. SFTP can list remote files (along with other features), I did not mean to imply that it could not. I ment that using SSH would negate the file transfer function while offering the desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it said in the comments the best way to do is using ssh. So this outputs what I wanted

`ssh user@123.45.67.8 ls /home/user/datafolder/ddd* | wc -l`

Answer (score 0):

`rsync --list-only` provides a succinct way to list the files in a remote directory. Simply passing the result to `wc -l` takes care of the count (excluding the `.` and `..` (dot) files), e.g.

```
rsync --list-only server:/path/to/dir/ | wc -l
```

(note the trailing `'/'` to count the **contents** rather than the directory itself. Add `-r` for a recursive count. You have all `rsync` options available to tailor the files counted, e.g. `--exclude="stuff"`, etc.)